# Datatable inputs get along with row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have added inputs for only 10 columns in my datatable and trying to save with button click. Below is my code

```
 $('#tblFormBtn').click( function() {
   let datas = tblListUpload.$("input").serializeArray();
 });
```

it's getting all the inputs in separate array values. Is it possible to get that array by row?

`Update:`
working sample
http://live.datatables.net/bucawete/1/

Comment: A working example would much help us to help you..

Comment: @MoshFeu working sample added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [map](https://datatables.net/reference/api/map()) each [row](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().nodes()) to create a `serializeArray`, here's an example:

```js
const table = $('#example').DataTable();
const data = table.rows().nodes().map((e) => $(e).find('input, select').serializeArray());
console.log(data.toArray());
```

```html
<link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="row-1-age" name="row-1-age" value="61"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="row-1-position" name="row-1-position" value="System Architect"></td>
      <td>
        <select size="1" id="row-1-office" name="row-1-office">
          <option value="Edinburgh" selected="selected">Edinburgh</option>
          <option value="London">London</option>
          <option value="New York">New York</option>
          <option value="San Francisco">San Francisco</option>
          <option value="Tokyo">Tokyo</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="row-2-age" name="row-2-age" value="63"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="row-2-position" name="row-2-position" value="Accountant"></td>
      <td>
        <select size="1" id="row-2-office" name="row-2-office">
          <option value="Edinburgh">Edinburgh</option>
          <option value="London">London</option>
          <option value="New York">New York</option>
          <option value="San Francisco">San Francisco</option>
          <option value="Tokyo" selected="selected">Tokyo</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
```